# Is it possible to add the ELB dynamically to Spinnaker

Tags: devops, spinnaker

Is there way to add the load balancer name dynamically in Spinnaker? Say for example, I have a Pipeline which does the bake and deploy the AMI in the ASG for different environment. In Deploy Phase for Cluster definition, I don't want to hardcode the ELB name and instead read from properties file.
This I can use the same pipeline for different environment.
Any thoughts or ideas?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

perform the 'add load balancer' action via deck while having the inspection panel open in the network tab. capture the API call. you'll notice there's a json payload. you can modify and subsequently script that action.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the pipeline config and under the Deploy stage edit the appropriate "Deploy Configuration". Select the load balancer use a Spring Expression like:

`${ trigger.properties.LB_NAME }`

This assumes you have pre-provisioned a loadbalancer that matches the `LB_NAME` passed in the trigger properties file.